# about ajax php and json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

MY ajax code looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".respond").submit(function(event){
  ..................//something here
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/check.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {formData:serializedData,submit_type:submit_name},
        datetype: JSON
    });
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(response);
    });
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });
    request.always(function () {
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

And when i use php code like this

```
var_dump($_POST["formData"]);
```

It gives result like this

```
"string(400) "user_edit=submit&user_id=1 ..........
"
```

I want to store userid in php variable like this

```
$username=......
```

But when i try doing like this

```
$username=$_POST["formData"]["userid"]
```

it gives error

> "
>  **Warning**:  Illegal string offset 'user_edit' in
>   **C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\admin\check.php** on line
>   **5**
>  string(1) "u" "

I want to know how to i get the value of that userid or something like that.

Comment: You are passing serialized data as a post parameter. PHP will only unserialize the first layer for you

Comment: @php_nub_qq then what should i do?/////

Comment: You should use `parse_str` but the example given in the answers is not correct, you should use `parse_str($_POST['formData'],$_POST['formData'])`

Comment: @php_nub_qq Yea it is sucessfully working man... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you see when dumping formData, it is a string! You want to access an element of it as it was an array -> error.

A better approach could be to include 'submit_type' in your form and just have

```
data: serialisedFormData
```

as your post data.

Comment: data: {formData:serializedData,submit_type:submit_name}

i want to check the name of submit button so i also added submit type..i cannot remove it actually :(

Comment: then i want to show the name of submit button how do i send that button name along with form data through ajax

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `formData` is a serialized string. So on the server side page where you are sending AJAX call you have to parse the serialized string using [PHP parse_str function](https://www.php.net/parse_str). So on the php page you should write something as :

```
<?php
$formdata = $_POST['formData'];
// For example I suppose that formData has values something like : first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz
//then
parse_str($formdata);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz

?>
```

Comment: when i var_dump($formdata) it gives NULL. So,

Comment: Then I am afraid that your form data are not passed when you make AJAX call. Debug using firebug. What data are sent via AJAX ?

Comment: these data were sent through ajax 
"array(2) {
  ["formData"]=>
  string(400) "user_edit=submit&user_id=1&user_email=sdfafsdfsdf%40gmail.com&user_name=dsfdsfsdfsdf&user_password=sdfdsfr"
  ["submit_type"]=>
  string(11) "user_update"
}

Comment: do var_dump($_POST) and try to get the serialized formData into $formdata variable and then use the code I have given.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) is given in question....and in your code when i try to var_dump(parse_str($_POST)) it gives result NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="ajax-form-submit.php" method="POST">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value =""/> <br/>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value ="" /> <br/>
  Email : <input type="text" name="email" value=""/> <br/>
 </form>

//callback handler for form submit
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
  var postData = $(this).serializeArray(); //note here serialize it before post it to server
  var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
  $.ajax(
  {
    url : formURL,
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data: return data from server
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        //if fails     
    }
  });
 e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
 e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});

 $("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
```

Then try to print_r($_POST) on your server php file, i think it will work for you

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => user_edit=submit
    [1] => user_id=1
    [2] => user_email=dfsdsf%40gmail.com
    [3] => user_name=shidsfdsf
    [4] => user_password=glitter
    [5] => user_firstname=dsf
    [6] => user_lastname=dsfdsf
    [7] => user_ip=127.0.0.1
    [8] => user_country=Nepal
    [9] => user_reset_key=
    [10] => user_activation_code=
    [11] => user_birthday=Sun%2C+07
    [12] => user_signupdate=Wed%2C+25+Jun+2014+06%3A00%3A00
    [13] => user_group=1
    [14] => user_notifications=1
    [15] => user_verified=Y
    [16] => user_reseted=N
    [17] => user_blocked=N
)

Comment: is it your printed result i mean print_r($_POST[]); ??

Comment: no it is after exploding.....The result printed after print_r($_POST) is given in question